# Nodejs batch download script : making an HTTP request inside JSONStream "on" event for

Tags: node.js, http, request

I have a weird problem. If I call this code to make an http request in the main execution line:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
    }
})
```

The Google page HTML is printed, as expected.

However, I am doing a batch download script/crawler, so I am parsing a very large JSON file and then performing a request for each of the URLs I produce from that file.

To do the parsing, I am using the JSONStream parser. Here is the code:

```
parser.on('data', function (obj) {
    console.log("Found uri");
    console.log(obj);
});
```

The code is being run correctly, as the URI's are being printed in my console.

However, if I make the request inside the parsing block, the request callback is never executed.... Here is the code:

```
parser.on('data', function (obj) {

    console.log("Found uri");
    console.log(obj);

    var identifierArray = obj['dc.identifier'];

    if(identifierArray != null && identifierArray instanceof Array)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < identifierArray.length; i++)
        {
            var dryadIdentifier = identifierArray[i];
            if(dryadIdentifier.indexOf("dryad") != -1)
            {
                var fullUrl = "http://datadryad.org/resource/"+dryadIdentifier+"/mets.xml"
                //var fileDestination = __dirname +"/"+downloadSubDir+"/"+dryadIdentifier.replace("/","_")+".xml"
                var fileDestination = __dirname +"/"+downloadSubDir+"/"+fileCounter+".xml";

                fileCounter++;

                console.log("Sending request to "+ fullUrl + "   ...");

               //REQUEST SENT HERE; SAME CODE AS ABOVE.

                var request = require('request');
                request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                        console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
                    }
                })

                sleep.usleep(500000); //dont hammer the server
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The log shows

```
Sending request to http://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.s737f/mets.xml   ...
Sending request to http://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.s737f/1/mets.xml   ...
Sending request to http://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.1fd83/mets.xml   ...
Sending request to http://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.1fd83/1/mets.xml   ...
Sending request to http://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.4vk6d/mets.xml   ...
Sending request to http://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.c3k8m/mets.xml   ...
Sending request to http://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.5410v/mets.xml   ...
Sending request to http://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.492r0/mets.xml   ...
Sending request to http://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.m6g1b/mets.xml   ...
Sending request to http://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.m6g1b/1/mets.xml   ...
Sending request to http://datadryad.org/resource/doi:10.5061/dryad.4dm30/mets.xml   ...
```

But no html is printed (it should print the google homepage many times, as I am not using the url's I parse from the json yet, to rule out problems with the intended server.

Sorry for the long letter, but I am at a loss at this behaviour (still learning nodejs... :-O)

Comment: Placing the var request = require('request'); line outside of the parser.on block does not change the situation.

Comment: Is there any chance that the requests fail, and your condition `response.statusCode == 200` is not satisfied?

Comment: Also - you are mixing up synchronous code execution (the for loop) with async callbacks. This code does not guarantee that responses will be in the same order as the loop. Just have that in mind.

Comment: Yeah, nice points you make there, thanks Slavo. I ended up solving this by removing the sleep call (apparently it holds execution) and using the semaphore library in nodejs to implement a basic queue to avoid ramming the server with requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue was related to the "sleep" call, so I implemented a basic connection queue with the [semaphore](https://npmjs.org/package/semaphore) library. I now specify a maximum of 10 simultaneous connections, here is my code:

```
var makeRequestAndSaveToFile = function(url, absolutePath)
{
    sem.take(function(){
        console.log("Sending request to "+ url + "   ... and saving to file "+absolutePath);
        request(url, function(error,response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                fs.writeFile(absolutePath, body, function(err) {
                    sem.leave();

                    if(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log("The file was saved!");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I call this function for each link I want to download.

Note that this will not handle big downloads as there is no piping, and the links will be downloaded in an unorderly fashion like Slavo said in his comments.